# Can I capture photos in Raw mode on iPhone 6 without have to pay for a 3rd party app?

Tags: iphone, photos

I am looking for a solution (preferably free of cost) to capture photos in RAW mode on my iPhone 6. The solution/tool should be able to capture RAW mode image before camera converts to JPEG/PNG.

I am also willing to Jailbreak the device if required.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in camera app in iOS doesn't support capturing RAW photos. You'll have to rely on a 3rd party app.

Since you are not looking for a paid app, you can download [VSCO](https://itunes.apple.com/app/vsco/id588013838) a free app that supports capturing photos in RAW mode.

OTOH, on the paid front, [Halide Camera](https://itunes.apple.com/app/halide-camera/id885697368) is a highly regarded app by photography enthusiasts and power users alike.

**Note**: No affiliation whatsoever. The answer is based on personal experience and ratings on the App Store.